# Imported Card using POST to wallet/import not available upon composer card list command

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Why is it I can't see the imported card thru POST request to wallet/import api when I issue composer card list command? Also I am encountering an business network card has not been specified error. Take note that I can see already the name of the wallet in GET wallet api. It is just that I can't see the card using composer card list. I don't know what is the problem. Below are the steps i made. Thank you.

1. Issue an identity to the participant thru POST

http://localhost:3000/api/system/identities/issue

2. Step 1 will response the .card file. Then import wallet by requesting POST

http://localhost:3000/api/wallet/import

3. execute composer card list command. Result was that the imported wallet is not available and upon authentication of the user. Issued access token returns business network card has not been specified upon calling other endpoint using the token.

Answer (score 0):

When using the Composer REST Server in MultiUser mode, Authentication is also enabled.  When a User Authenticates, any Card they import will be stored in the Datasource specified when the REST server is started.  So if you are following the Composer Documentation, you will probably be using MongoDB as the persisted store for the REST server.  (If you have not set a Datasource for the REST server, then the Wallets are not persisted and will not be available when the REST server is restarted).

Using the CLI, cards are by default stored in the File System wallet under the home folder `~/.composer` and these cards can be seen with `composer card list`.

Comment: You are right. I am storing the the wallet in MongoDB. The problem I currently encountering with that is upon authentication of the user, I can't use the generated access_token to call other endpoints as it gives me an "A business network card has not been specified" error.  So maybe, the composer doesn't look for a cards stored in defined data source. My problem is I don't know how to point the composer to look for a wallet stored in data source(MongoDB or Cloudant).

Comment: Just so you know. Below is my settings for composer rest server:

COMPOSER_CARD=admin@sample-network
COMPOSER_NAMESPACES=never
COMPOSER_AUTHENTICATION=true
COMPOSER_MULTIUSER=true
COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
  "jwt": {
    "provider": "jwt",
    "module": "/home/composer/node_modules/custom-jwt.js",
    "secretOrKey": "secretOrKey",
    "authScheme": "saml",
    "successRedirect": "/",
    "failureRedirect":"/"
    }
}'
COMPOSER_DATASOURCES='{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "host": "mongo"
  }
}'

Comment: After you authenticate, you need to do a POST at /wallet/import to get a card into the wallet of the Authenticated user.  

(When you import a card, beware of the one-time secret issue described in this recent Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778110/hyperledger-using-google-oauth2-0-with-a-rest-server )

Comment: Yes, I was able to import the card using that POST request. However where I try to login the user it wasn't able to see the card that with the fact that I was already able to view the imported card when I try to GET request to api/wallet.