# Hyperledger, Using Google OAUTH2.0 with a REST server

Tags: rest, google-oauth, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I deployed the network to query from the REST client and launched the REST instance. I wanted to use Google Oauth for the authentication needs but there happens to be an authentication error.

The network is on the localhost:3000 and looks fine; however, when I import a business card and "try it out" the /system/historian I get this response body:

"error": {
"statusCode": 500,
"name": "Error",
"message": "Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]",
"stack": "Error: Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]\n at client.getUserContext.then.then.catch (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:395:34)\n at \n at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)"

The expected behaviour was to get a set of transactions showed up

I checked the wallet, thinking I might have a problem with the card but there seems to be no problem. The code is 200 which is expected, and here is the response body:

[
{
"name": "liner1",
"default": false
},
{
"name": "liner1@iot-perishable-network-advanced",
"default": true
}
]

Answer (score 0):

If you have got as far as importing a card to a Wallet, then your Google Oauth config is fine.

This looks like a problem with the card you have imported.  When the Identity is Issued (and the Card is created) a one-time secret is created. When the card is used for the first time the secret is exchanged for Certificates/Keys and the the one-time secret is invalidated.

I'm guessing that you have imported a .card file for a user which has already been used, so now the secret is invalid.  If I'm right, you need to export the card from the place where it is working to a new .card file that contains the certificates/keys, and import that new .card file into the REST server wallet.  Maybe the command `composer card export` is what you are looking for.

There is more information on cards in the [Composer Knowledge Wiki](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#bizcards).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "file for a user which has already been used". I believe I figured out the problem though. You are right about the card having the problem. When I go to my playground, I see that there are two "Connection"s with the same name and 2 of my cards are under one, the other two cards are under the other connection. When I try to connect via restadmin card or participant card, I get the same error I get from the Google Oauth REST. How can resist to put my cards under different connection?